# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException:activity.RegisterActivity.registerUser(RegisterActivity.java:247)

Tags: java, android, exception

why IDE say me EXCEPTION at the line 247 of Register Activity of my class?

this is the line code:

Register Activity:

```
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
```

I must post all code about this class?

P.S.:I have this exception when i click on button "register"

Comment: Can you post the method in which you are writing this code ? And possibly some more stack trace.

Comment: @NaveenAechan i posted method

Comment: Did you register your AppController in android Manifest file ? i.e; under application tag  android:name="<your pacage>.AppController" ?

Comment: no, i not registered XD

Comment: You have to register AppController first and try again and it should work.

Comment: yes, it works..THANKS!

Comment: Cool, you can upvote the answer, if that works for you.